# How to drag-and-drop on custom Swing components

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, user-experience

How can I implement drag and drop on custom components, e.g. my own `JPanel` subclasses?

What I need is full Swing-like drag and drop support. With `TransferHandlers`, `DropTargetListeners` etc. So the trivial `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: For `JPanel` you need to initiate the drag gesture, and that usually comes from handling `mousePressed()` and calling `getTransferHandler().exportAsDrag()`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Lesson: Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html).

Comment: Please at least read and understand the question and make sure what you're posting is at least in some way related and helpful. The question was asked for expert feedback, not a random RTFM-style copy&paste from Google.